# How to display localized form title and form description in the builder summary page?

Tags: orbeon

The Form Builder Summary Page is not displaying localized form title and form description. You can choose any language you want, they always appear in the english version. If english version is not defined in the forms languages, they do not appear.

Does someone have a hint on this ? Seems to be a bug.

Comment: Which version of Orbeon Forms are you using? I am not aware of this being an issue.

Comment: Orbeon 4.3.1, build 30/08/2013

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be a recent regression. I entered an [issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1376) and the fix will be in 4.4.